# Specialize function by traits class

Tags: c++, templates, traits

I'm writing a hash functor for use in a `boost::unordered_map` which will store `boost::graph` edge descriptors. Simple enough. Undirected and directed graph edges must be hashed differently however (at least in my case, the edges `(u,v)` and `(v,u)` are equivalent when the graph is undirected, so `map[(u,v)]` and `map[(v,u)]` must point at the same value). I can detect directedness with the graph traits class (`boost::graph_traits<Graph>::directed_category`), but how can I define different implementations using templates?

Below is what I've got so far, but I don't want the `if` clause. Instead I want `EdgeHash` to compiles different versions of `operator()` depending on the value of `directed_category`. How can this be achieved?

```
template <typename Graph>
struct EdgeHash {
    typedef typename boost::graph_traits<Graph>::edge_descriptor Edge;
    std::size_t operator()(const Edge& e) const {
        std::size_t hash = 0;
        if(boost::is_same<boost::graph_traits<Graph>::directed_category, boost::directed_tag>::value) {
            boost::hash_combine(hash, e.m_source);
            boost::hash_combine(hash, e.m_target);
        } else {
            boost::hash_combine(hash, std::min(e.m_source, e.m_target));
            boost::hash_combine(hash, std::max(e.m_source, e.m_target));
        }
        return hash;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put hashing in a separate struct templated on directed category type.

```
template<typename Directed, typename Edge>
struct Hasher {
    static std::size_t edge_hash(const Edge& e) {
        std::size_t hash = 0;
        boost::hash_combine(hash, e.m_source);
        boost::hash_combine(hash, e.m_target);
        return hash;
    }
};

template<typename Edge>
struct Hasher<boost::directed_tag, Edge> {
    static std::size_t edge_hash(const Edge& e) {
        std::size_t hash = 0;
        boost::hash_combine(hash, std::min(e.m_source, e.m_target));
        boost::hash_combine(hash, std::max(e.m_source, e.m_target));
        return hash;
    }
};

template <typename Graph>
struct EdgeHash {
    typedef typename boost::graph_traits<Graph>::edge_descriptor Edge;
    std::size_t operator()(const Edge& e) const {
        return Hasher<
            boost::graph_traits<Graph>::directed_category,
            Edge>::edge_hash(e);
    }
};
```

Comment: There are a few errors in your code; a forgotten `typename` in the general `Hasher`, not calling `edge_hash` in `operator()`, and inversed logic (that might be my fault on the other hand...). But fixing that, it works. Thank you!

Comment: Fixed. Also, since Hasher is a utility type, you may want to hide it e.g. by making it a private nested (member) class of EdgeHash.

Comment: Great! I've acually put it in an anonymous namespace, so that is not a problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `boost::enable_if`, you can do this, however, you have to specialize the structure. e.g (untested)

```
template <typename Graph, class Enable = void>
struct EdgeHash {
    typedef typename boost::graph_traits<Graph>::edge_descriptor Edge;
    std::size_t operator()(const Edge& e) const {
        std::size_t hash = 0;
        boost::hash_combine(hash, std::min(e.m_source, e.m_target));
        boost::hash_combine(hash, std::max(e.m_source, e.m_target));
        return hash;
    }
};

template <typename Graph>
struct EdgeHash<Graph, typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_same<boost::graph_traits<Graph>::directed_category, boost::directed_tag> >::type>
{
    typedef typename boost::graph_traits<Graph>::edge_descriptor Edge;
    std::size_t operator()(const Edge& e) const {
        std::size_t hash = 0;
        boost::hash_combine(hash, e.m_source);
        boost::hash_combine(hash, e.m_target);
        return hash;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe adding one bool template parameter in the actual EdgeHash class? For instance:

```
template <typename Graph, bool is_directed>
struct EdgeHashImpl {
    typedef typename boost::graph_traits<Graph>::edge_descriptor Edge;
    std::size_t operator()(const Edge& e) const {
        std::size_t hash = 0;
        boost::hash_combine(hash, e.m_source);
        boost::hash_combine(hash, e.m_target);
    return hash;
   }
};

template <typename Graph>
struct EdgeHashImpl <Graph, false>
{
  typedef typename boost::graph_traits<Graph>::edge_descriptor Edge;
  std::size_t operator()(const Edge& e) const {
      std::size_t hash = 0;
      boost::hash_combine(hash, std::min(e.m_source, e.m_target));
      boost::hash_combine(hash, std::max(e.m_source, e.m_target));
      return hash;
   }
};


template <typename Graph>
struct EdgeHash 
: public EdgeHashImpl
  <Graph, boost::is_same<boost::graph_traits<Graph>::directed_category, boost::directed_tag>::value)>
{};
```